# bdist using old files to create built distribution

Tags: setup.py, software-distribution, python-wheel

I'm trying to build a wheel file for my python package. I run

```
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

The package appears to build successfully (no error messages). But the built distribution contains versions of my files from a previous build.

What's going on and how can I create a built distribution with my latest files?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `bdist_wheel` was copying files from the `build/` folder into the `.whl` file.

I solved it by deleting the `build/` folder and runing `$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` again.